# ASP.NET: Edit App_GlobalResources with precompiled web

Tags: asp.net, localization

Is there any options to editing the resources in the App_GlobalResources folder? Once compiled, the directory is not included as part of the precompiled folder.

I read online that the App_GlobalResources Resources are compiled into a DLL for easy access. However, I want the administrator to be able to update the content of these files. Is the only way to convert these GlobalResources .RESX into LocalResources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to edit the files "in place" once they're compiled - but why not just make your changes, precompile the web again, and then just deploying the App_GlobalResources.compiled and App_GlobalResources.dll separately to your website? That should update the global resource DLL and should achieve what you're looking for, I think.

Marc

Comment: Because I would like to give this access to a person without acccess to Visual Studios. Thanks for the answer cause it will help for the time being.

Comment: You're welcome. What you might think about in the meantime is a "hybrid" solution: basically keep your text strings in App_GlobalResources, but offer some way for the user to override those setting e.g. by placing replacements in a database table temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom small resource editor application, this will be separate from your main application.

The GlobalResource Editor application will open a form which shows Keys in the first column and values in another column.

You can compile this application and copy and paste the `app_globalresource` file to your main application.

This way you can also ask your customer to use this application and teach him to copy and paste the resource file after compilation.